# How to drop duplicate from a pandas dataframe with some complex conditions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I am trying to drop duplicates, but based on some conditions. My dataframe looks like this:

```
idx  a    b    c   d   e  f
1    1   ss1   0   25  A  B
2    3   ss7   0   25  A  B
3    5   ss5   0   12  C  D
4    11  im3   0   12  C  D
5    5   ss8   0   50  C  K
6    9   im8   0   5   F  G
7    8   ix6   0   5   F  G
```

Rows are considered duplicates if the values of columns **d**, **e** and **f** together match other records in the dataframe `subset=['d', 'e', 'f']`. For example, rows 1 and 2 are duplicates, rows 3 and 4 are duplicates, and rows 6 and 7 are duplicates. The selection of which row to drop is based on column **b**.

1. If the value in column `b` begins with **ss** for both duplicates (rows 1 and 2), then anyone can be dropped
2. If one of the duplicates begins with **ss** and the other begins with a different format (rows 3 and 4), then the one that begins with **ss** should be kept.
3. If both duplicates in column `b` begin with anything **other** than **ss** (rows 6 and 7), then anyone can be selected.

Therefore, the expected output should be something like this:

```
idx  a    b    c   d   e  f
2    3   ss7   0   25  A  B
3    5   ss5   0   12  C  D
5    5   ss8   0   50  C  K
7    8   ix6   0   5   F  G
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort by `b` key first (everything starts by 'ss' is moved to the end) then drop duplicates from `['d', 'e', 'f']` (keep the last):

```
out = (df.sort_values('b', key=lambda x: x.str.startswith('ss'))
         .drop_duplicates(['d', 'e', 'f'], keep='last').sort_index())

# OR

out = (df.sort_values('b', key=lambda x: x.str.startswith('ss'))
         .groupby(['d', 'e', 'f'], as_index=False).nth(-1).sort_index())
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   idx  a    b  c   d  e  f
1    2  3  ss7  0  25  A  B
2    3  5  ss5  0  12  C  D
4    5  5  ss8  0  50  C  K
6    7  8  ix6  0   5  F  G
```

Comment: Thankx for your help. It works perfectly if you insert the results in a new dataframe, but if  I want to run it on the same dataframe adding 'inplace = True' throws an error 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sort_index' '

Comment: If you use inplace modification, pandas does not return a dataframe so you can't chain any other methods like set_index. Using inplace will be deprecated in future version of pandas.